# Need to convert a batch of wav in flac in different folder

Tags: find, batch-jobs, flac

I need to convert a lot of *.wav in different folder, i try to use find and flac to convert all this without missing name of the track in the folder.

This is the line I try to use :

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.wav" -exec sh -c flac -8 *.wav \;
```

I don't know what missing but flac show me the man. I think I need some help :)

ps : I find a "solution" but with ffmpeg, I prefer using flac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call a subshell for the `find` arguments here, you can call directly `flac`. Also the command you execute accepts multiple arguments, so you can call one `flac` process to convert all your files, like this:

```bsh
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" -exec flac -8 {} +
```

Comment: Note: the output files will have same name, different extension, e.g. `test.wav` -> `test.flac`.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks